# how various clients of my website can send WhatsApp messages to their respective audience?

Tags: node.js, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am a developer. working on a project where I need to integrate my site with WhatsApp API to send messages. Moreover, I want my various clients can send messages to their respective audiences with their own numbers. How can I achieve that?

I have checked only BSPs can create a WhatsApp Business platform on WhatsApp cloud API. BSPs can provide such a solution. However, there is no mention of how to integrate or embed the form with the website so clients can fill and register themselves.

Comment: Here everything is quite simple: either use official providers (take their documentation and make integration to the site yourself, taking into account all the restrictions), or use unofficial whatsapp api - more possibilities, but not safe. So it probably depends on your end goals, your resources and capabilities.

Comment: @Hafiz  I have checked the solution, I can add numbers up to 20 to my WhatsApp cloud API. But I have some confusion if I can do this with the developer's account or just BSPs can do this. because they have given API request but mentioned the embedded signup process before 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/solution-providers/phone-numbers/registering-phone-numbers

Comment: Yes, if you want to connect your own clients, the Cloud API won't work for you. Only as a BSP partner you can connect new numbers of your clients (just using the embedded signup form). You can try to become a reseller with any BSP

Comment: @Hafiz can't we add a few client numbers under our CRM? without registering every client's business under our one CRM. as per the above link, can we just add the client's mobile number and display name of a business?

Comment: Multiple numbers can be added to one business, but only if they belong to that business.